# How to check the value of Σ character in an Excel Cell? - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I do have a cell in excel that contains Σh. Not sure how to check for it in vba. I have tried with `.Value` and `.Text`, but the check is never true.

[image]

```
If (tRange.Value = (ChrW(931) + "h")) Then
    Exit Sub
End if
```

---

When testing (Debug) I get this result for `ActiveCell.Value` = `Sh`

[image]

Comment: Any possible invisible characters in `tRange`? Or even wrong implicit sheet-referencing? Btw, you don't need this nesting; `tRange.Value = ChrW(931) + "h"` should do where `+` is interchangable with `&` when using string values. For good measure use the latter as @Ike has shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should check if cell value contains the sub-string 'Σh'

```
If tRange.Value Like "*" & ChrW(931) & "h*" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Another maybe simpler way for some folks

```
If InStr(1, tRange.Value, ChrW(931) & "h") <> 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

**(a)** You have to use `.Value` to get the content of the cell.
**(b)** You should use the ampersand character (`&`) to concatenate strings in VBA. The plus-sign works also, but only if all operands are strings.
**(c)** `ChrW(931) & "h"` (or `ChrW(931) + "h"`) should work. VBA is able to handle characters even if the VBA-environment cannot show them.

Seems to me that either the Sigma-character is composed with a different character, or your cell contains invisible characters like space, newline, tabs...

You can dump the content of the cell with the following code to get an idea why your `If`-statement fails:

```
Sub DumpString(s As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim c As String
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        Debug.Print i, AscW(c), c
    Next
End Sub
```

When you enter the following command into the **immediate window**, you will see output like that:

```
 DumpString activecell.Value
   1             931          S
   2             104          h
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an ampersand to join the two characters:

```vb
If (tRange.Value = ChrW(931) & "h") Then
    Exit Sub
End if
```

Comment: Funny enough, `+` will work with these two string-variables and shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: You should use `&` to join, but you don't have to, as is clear in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/plus-operator).